# If the Iraq War was because of their oil, has the US achieved their war aims

Tags: united-states, war, middle-east

Let's assume:

```
The United States of America started the 2003 Iraq war to obtain Iraqi oil.
```

The Iraq war was very costly for the Americans, and a long and unfinished war has always made the countries that fight them weaker. It is possible, in part, that the financial crisis in America was because of this war. Iraq isn't in better shape because of this long war.

So, for the United States, was this war worth fighting? Will this benefit the US in the long run financially or otherwise?

Comment: Why should we assume any such thing?

Comment: Because this is a common critic of this war. One big motive was because the weapons of mass destruction but none was found.

Comment: Rodrigo - Actually, that's a pretty good answer to my question. However, I'm pretty sure its not true (as a voting American I think I can say that), so any logic based off that assumption is the rhetorical equivalent of dividing by zero in a math proof.

Comment: Oil was never a stated goal at the beginning of this, originally it was Weapons of Mass Destruction then fighting the terrorists there rather than here.  So while your assumption as a basis is interesting it was never a stated goal, other than from those who opposed the Bush Administration.

Comment: @MichaelF, While that is certainly true, US officials did quite publicly state that Iraqi oil revenues would be more than adequate to cover the cost of American intervention as an incentive to go to war (which assumed that the US had a right to Iraqi oil to cover an invasion which the Iraqi people hadn't been consulted on). Americans also forced through major oil concessions (to benefit American companies) in Iraq's constitution.  So while oil acquisition was never a stated goal, it was clearly stated that Iraqi oil should go to American interests.

Comment: @BrotherJack Regardless, it was not a stated goal for invasion, try to keep focus on my comments please.

Comment: @MichaelF, sorry if it got a little off track.  All I was trying to say was that it was mentioned as an incentive even by members of the Bush administration (Rumsfield specifically), even though to the best of my knowledge, it was never mentioned as a stated goal.  So I can see why the asker might see it as a stated goal.

Comment: @MichaelF - No, it was not an "incentive". What they were trying to say is that what they wanted to do for other reasons (go to war) would be financially painless because of the oil revenues, so people arguing against doing it because of cost should shut up. One trillion dollars later, that argument was clearly bunk.

Comment: This dicusssion is a perfect example of why I flagged this question. As phrased it is essentially political flame-bait, and it can't lead anywhere productive, as the entire premise is wrong.

Comment: Long story short, the assumption is true.

Comment: @T.E.D. I didn't mention incentive, are you posting something to me?

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson - I'm American, and I say you're wrong. I can produce oodles of backup, in the form of fellow Americans (oddly, I'm surrounded by them here) who remember quite vividly why they were in support of it. What can you produce?

Comment: @MichaelF - Sorry. It appears that comment was meant for BrotherJack. Lack of threading in these comments leads to confusion. Of course if this situation arises, it probably indicates the question or answer being commented on was flamebait rather than a useful contribution to the site...

Comment: you can be as many as you like, that  doesn't make you any more right. i can produce a reference to comment number 5, by BrotherJack.

Comment: @HermannIngjaldsson - ..which was taken out of context and then badly (and perhaps purposely) misinterprted. Think about this logically for just one second please. If all we wanted was oil, why not knock off Saudi Arabia or Venezuela instead? Either would have been far easier, and netted more oil. Unless...I don't know...there were **other reasons**.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about counter-factual speculation. It's too old to migrate, but nowadays people tend to vote to close question that are about politics or based on false assumptions.

Comment: @T.E.D. And if it was about stealing oil: Why would they then give the control over the oil back to the Iraqi? :-)

Comment: The problem I have with the question isn't the assumption (`true/false/tastes like chicken`) but that regardless of the 'outcome' of the assumption, the two actual enquiries in the question are not cohesive or unique to the assumption; and hence you could ask exactly the same question without the assumption and friction it has caused. Mind you, the actual query sentences of this question solicit opinion-based answers anyway (at least within the size limits of the *history.se* Q&A format)

Comment: even more damning, had the US contracted with Iraq to provide them black market oil, like France had for example, they'd have gotten all that oil at below market prices and at zero cost in equipment and human life, a far more profitable venture.

Comment: After one year I think I fulfill my goal. The answer say and I believe it is true, it is too simplistic believe that this war started because the oil. Was good see all the opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd say controlling oil possibly played some role in the desire to go to war, but it was neither the sole reason or necessarily the impetus to start the war.  My analysis of why neoconservative leaders such as Cheney, Rumsfeld, and Wolfowitz were determined to war with Iraq was based on several factors.  First, Iraq's location serves as a perfect buffer between major American allies Israel and Saudi Arabia, and Iran.  A strong pro-American government in Baghdad would help to ensure that Iranian influence would be minimized in he region.

Also, many of the neoconservatives at the time were deeply influenced by the Vietnam war, which soured many American's towards the imperialist policy of the neocons throughout the 60's, 70's and into the 1980's.  At the end of the cold war there was also a need to justify American military presence overseas and with the 9/11 attacks there was the opportunity to do so.  However, this would require more than a police action against Al Qaeda and more of a full on international war.  Given the mindset of the neoconservatives, I doubt the former was ever considered even if it were far more rational given that Al Qaeda is a non-state actor.

Financially, oil was probably less of a motive than the lucrative military contracts and expenditures that a war and occupation could provide.  Furthermore, this was an opportunity for people like Cheney and his former company Haliburton, to not only make a killing off of an almost endless stream of government money, but to also remake the military in accordance with their ideological principles.  A significant development in the U.S. Iraq war of 2003 was the privatization of the army.  Not only in a non-combat contractor force to provide services (often at inflated rates), but in a massive mercenary force employed to protect state department officials and other security tasks.  The latter also allowed the US to recruit soldiers from all over the world, even in countries that opposed the war.  Even more frighteningly, the gray area concerning the legal status of mercenaries allowed them to perform tasks which were certain illegal and immoral.  Mercenary companies such as Blackwater (renamed **Xe** and now **Academi**) do not have to disclose their activities as they are considered "trade secrets" and their employees only faced being fired even after it was shown that they would engage in insanely aggressive acts (such as running over traffic and opening fire on civilians) to dissuade any attacks on their state department officials.  Given that the state department officials were the ones both being protected AND charged with investigating mercenary groups, Blackwater was able to avoid any serious threat from the US government.

Anyway, to answer your question, the war itself was not necessarily that costly to the US.  The following occupation has proved to be extremely costly.  Not only has the US spent a considerable amount of money and resources attempting to secure the country, but Iran wound up gaining a far greater degree of influence over the region than they have for decades (Iran was very unpopular in Iraq due to the very bitter and bloody Iran-Iraq war).  The US did a lot to try and impose American (specifically neoconservative) values on the Iraqis, and took measures such as imposing their chosen political leaders and writing large portions of the Iraqi constitution.  In addition to the flagrant abuses by the likes of Blackwater and the imposition of American military bases, this lead many Iraqis to take up arms and accept support from even Iranian associated groups.  The Iraq war also played in with many of the abuses of the "Global War on Terror", severely damaging American civil liberties and freedoms.

This war was damaging in so many ways that it is hard to mention them all.  There are a lot of good books on the subject from so many angles.  I'd recommend [Jeremy Scahill's Blackwater: The Rise of the World's Most Powerful Mercenary Army](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1560259795) for the damaging effects of the military industrial complex and America's recent turn towards mercenaries.  The late East Asian scholar Chalmers Johnson has a whole series of books ([Blowback](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805075593), [Sorrows of Empire](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805077979), and [Nemesis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001P3OMM8)) and a [bunch of articles on alternet](http://www.alternet.org/authors/5787/) which detail the harm imperial overreach has on the US.  Finally, a good book on getting the mindset which led to the American invasion is provided by Rajiv Chandrasekaran in his [Imperial Life in the Emerald City: Inside Iraq's Green Zone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1400044871).

Comment: Saddam was not an Iranian ally and he was ready for anti-Iranian cooperation. His overthrow only strengthened Iranian influence in Iraq.

Comment: @Anixx yeah, I mentioned that Iraqis in general were angry with Iran due in large part to the Iran-Iraq war.  That definitely rings true for the man who actually started the war and ultimately failed to achieve anything close to his objectives.

Answer (score 1):

It can be surely believed that overall military investment is highly profitable for the United States.

The profit comes not only from the resources directly captured but from "soft power" that is based on the US military potential. By conducting such wars they show that they can easily overthrow any government whose policy they do not like very much and that no costs can stop them.

This is a very clear message to any other countries and governments which forces them to conduct pro-US policy such as implementing US-imposed legislation, conducting privatization and keeping their money in US banks.

Comment: China and Russia both vetoed action in Syria because they didn't want America to think that they could over-through any government they felt like. +1.

Comment: It seems that the war in Iraq has severely backfired in terms of US soft power. The international credibility and respect for the US declined *sharply* following the war, and the only message it sent was that we're a bunch of belligerents who will do whatever want no matter what everyone else says. That's the definition of hard power, not soft power.

Comment: @Russell - That's debatable. I'd argue they vetoed it because they both also have authoritarian goverments and would be doing the exact same thing as Syria's rulers in their shoes.

Comment: @TED any country would be doing the same. I think in the US a response to insurgency would be much more severe.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's highly profitable for the US.  Our nation is much further in debt as a result.  It would be more accurate to say it is highly profitable for the companies who get military contracts (who in turn give campaign contributions to the politicians).  Ordinary citizens do not profit.

Comment: @Anixx - People protesting in the streets is not "an insurgency". You can see exactly how the US responds to such things, because it happens every day here. Sometimes the cops go a little nutty, but I've never seen our army come out and shell an entire city.

Comment: @TED, we were discussing insurgency in Syria, were not we? There is an Syryan liberation army, supplied by Quatar, Turkey, Libya and other foreign powers. The casualties from the both sides are more or less equal with thousands military killed. Is it insurgency or not yet?...